# Get innerWidth of Bootstrap button (crossbrowser)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I'm trying to take the size (width) of a bootstrap button, but I have some strange behaviors.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span> Save This Item
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
var siHeight = $('button').innerHeight();
var siWidth = $('button').innerWidth();

$('button').on('click', function() {

   var iHeight = $('button').innerHeight();
   var iWidth = $('button').innerWidth();

   alert("On click H x W" + iHeight + " x " + iWidth + " Before click H x W " + siHeight + " x " + siWidth);

});
```

1. The innerWidth does not equal if taken before or after the button click event
2. The behavior is different for each browser used (IE10, Firefox. Chrome)

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/pVyPHEqqx2)

Can I get the same size before and after the click event with crossbrowser solution ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add some CSS to make the button not change when you click it:

```
.btn:focus,.btn:active {
     outline: none !important;
}
```

[Bootply of edited code with css](http://www.bootply.com/UjZiVIvsKZ)

Comment: Unfortunately with firefox and chrome the behavior does not change

Comment: Do you have to use innerWidth() and innerHeight()? If you just use width() and height() you will get consistent results with added css.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not true what you say. I used the height and width but with chrome or firefox the result is different http://www.bootply.com/ljxHqnfrKO

Answer (score 0):

The problem with "not equal before and after" is because css styles :active, :focus , :hover  has outline. In such cases you had better use the developer tools and check your css codes when :active, :focus, :hover.

[image: if you don t know how to check on dev tools]

On the other hand, you can simply use width instead of innerWidth.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately my second question remains unanswered